# PHP select Data based on latest and previous date data respect to ID from MySQL

Tags: php, date

Have a issue to Fetch data based on most resent date entry and show **"Data:abc1"**

And a second one is a bit tricky

fetch Most resent data: **"abc2"** Which is the next most previous data after the Current one for ID "12345"

Example:1

the latest date for **id:12345** is **2015-6-10 00:00:00** against A repeated data is **i.e : abc1**

```
   2015-6-10 00:00:00        13245         abc1
   2015-6-08 00:00:00        13245         abc1
   2015-6-05 00:00:00        13245         abc1 
   2015-6-06 00:00:00        13245         abc1
```

Expected output:1

```
abc1
```

Example:2

the most previous date for **id:12345** after Current data **i.e: abc1** is  **2015-4-10 00:00:00**

```
   2015-4-04 00:00:00        13245         abc2
   2015-4-10 00:00:00        13245         abc2
   2015-4-10 00:00:00        14555         abc2
```

Expected output:2

```
abc2
```

Database:

```
       TimeDate                id          data
   2015-6-10 00:00:00        13245         abc1
   2015-6-08 00:00:00        13245         abc1
   2015-6-05 00:00:00        13245         abc1 
   2015-6-06 00:00:00        13245         abc1
   2015-4-04 00:00:00        13245         abc2
   2015-4-10 00:00:00        13245         abc2
   2015-4-10 00:00:00        14555         abc2
```

PHP:

```
  $mysqli=mysqli_connect('localhost','Uname','Pass','Database');
                  $id = $_POST['idajax'];
            $query ="SELECT * FROM scores WHERE  ID='$id' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query)or die(mysqli_error());
    $num_row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {

        //Show result:




        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group by` clause to find most recent record of a specific id and data.

**Example**:

```
SELECT MAX( timedate ) AS timedate, id, data
  FROM scores
 GROUP BY id, data
```

You can include a `WHERE` clause to filter `id` or `data`

Comment: is it for php or MySQL query

Comment: I need in PHP as am using this for a application

Comment: You mean you want to use a `select * ...` and loop and compare in `PHP` to filter data???

Comment: @ Ravinder Reddy   yes

Comment: is that gona fetch the latest data based on date

Comment: No. use the logic suggested and apply the comparison.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80181/discussion-between-shaik-and-ravinder-reddy).

Comment: can you suggest me a Rehears of my question am new to this